# PHP arrays into javascript arrays

Tags: php, javascript

I am a bit confused here on how I implement an array into JS from PHP....

I'm doing this for testing - eventually I'll use long polling or websockets if they get highly supported but this is what I have:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT x,y,sid FROM player_town WHERE uid='1'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
$data = json_encode($row);
```

Further down the script I then put in the head:

```
<script>var data = Array(<? $data; ?>)</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
```

But in js.js it says undefined but $data is set. This is the error:

```
x is not defined
```

In js.js I did `alert(data[x]);` and I get undefined.

My json_encode looks like this:

```
{"x":"283","y":"99","sid":"1"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use AJAX and load the JSON object via a remote call to a PHP file that prints out that code. It'll be easier than directly injecting it into your script, as you can poll the file every so often and refresh the JS object.

Comment: What is `x`? You're not getting an error saying `data` is undefined. The 283 value is `data.x` or `data["x"]`, not `data[x]` (unless `x` happens to contain the string `"x"`.

Comment: Ah i see you edited :P which is more correct data.x or data["x"]?

Comment: They're operationally equivalent.

Comment: Please vastly improve the title. Listing the technologies PHP and Javascript doesn't describe the question to anybody.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is that better?

Comment: @Dave: My spidey senses say 50% there

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what do you suggest as a title ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you need to wrap the json string in an Array, you could just do

```
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
```

--

To get the value of data in your js, you can either do data.x or data["x"]

Comment: +1  Not sure why no one else is mentioning that the array is redundant... :)

Comment: Ah i see - i thought that would it to display on the page aswell! 

Though i still get the X not defined issue

Comment: @Dave: I address that in my (edited) comment to your question.

Comment: @Corbin: It's actually not "redundant", but invalid. There is no `Array` constructor taking an object as first argument.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you're `echo`ing the PHP data into the `<script>` tags

```
<script>var data = Array(<?php echo $data; ?>)</script>
```

As an aside, it's a good idea to avoid using short tags (`<?` and `?>`) in a production setting--many servers have them disabled by default, and it's a really annoying way to have your code break.

Comment: The php?> tag should be ?>. PHP will interpret that as php as a constant and then a closing tag (which is obviously not the intent).

Comment: Haha, thanks, you're absolutely right. And after a lecture on avoiding shorthand, no less...

Comment: Happens to everyone from time to time :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this instead:

```
var data = <?= $data ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if `<? $data; ?>` is a typo or not but you should be using either `<?=$data;?>` or `<?php echo $data; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX (much easier). Make your PHP script `echo $data`, and then using jQuery ajax request the data in your HTML file as JSON. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: script_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json)
    {
         ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer in your comments. I would make an AJAX call to yourFile.php and then send back your JSON encoded response. so here would be my psuedo code.

```
1. Make AJAX request

$.ajax({
    url: "yourFile.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
         console.log(data);
    }
});

2. Make sure that your PHP file also returns header for JSON

header('Content-type: application/json');

2. Return {"x":"283","y":"99","sid":"1"} as data on your ajax request


3. call the values by using data.x or data.y or data.sid
```